How do I hide the Gemini button in Google Messages?
Recently a Gemini button with a blue sparkle started appearing on the bottom right when I check my messages on the Google Messages app. I have no interest in using Google's AI service.
How do I get rid of the Gemini button in Google Messages?


To get rid of the Gemini button:

Open the Google Messages app
Tap your profile icon in the top right
Select Message Settings > Gemini in Messages
Turn off the "Show Gemini button" setting


